# Changing core functionality of Shopping Cart Price Rule

Tags: shipping, rules

To suite my Payment terms i have considered using Shopping Cart Price Rules since they are easy way out. What the default Shopping Cart Price Rule does is that it applies a fix or percentage based discount (whatever we set it to)-and then it subtracts that discount from subtotal amount BUT i want it to ADD the 'discount'* to subtotal amount and Grand-Total be based on ' Subtotal + discount* '. The discount* in my case would be shipping as i would change the word 'discount' by 'Shipping'. And so the Grand-Total would now be turned as 'Subtotal + Shipping'. So basically all that needs to be done is change the subtraction sign - to addition sign + , to perform addition of **Subtotal** **+** discount-turned-into-**Shipping**

You guys must be wondering why i am not using the default shipping options-well i tried them but they are not suiting my needs.

Anyone please?just need to know where can i perform maths.

Comment: It seems a really weird way to change core shopping cart discounts to suite your payment terms. What is it that you are trying to achieve? What are your payment terms, there may be a very simple way of achieving this rather than overwriting/changing core promotions.

Comment: Ok here is what payment summary is about:

Comment: @rob3000  I have two basic Payment Methods those are Cash On Delivery and Bank Transfer. Under COD, if the order is greater than $250 AND/OR 3kg the customer would have to pay the shipping charges in advance which is 20% of order amount and the outstanding dues would be paid when order reaches his address.

Comment: Ok could you not create a custom shipping method that could calculate this? There is a great tutorial by inchoo on how to achieve this (http://inchoo.net/magento/custom-shipping-method-in-magento/) I feel this would be a much better solution than changing core Shopping cart price functionality